# Test a submodule in Gradle as fast as possible (without configuring rest of projects)

Tags: java, android, gradle

I've got a module of an android app with all the logic and pojos so it can be tested quickly, the thing is that when I test that module Gradle spends most of the time configuring the 5 projects i have in the root application and are not related to the code i'm going to test.

Can I avoid that ?

I'm using: "gradle :core:test" command

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try setting the "Configure on demand" flag to true in your `gradle.properties` file

```
org.gradle.configureondemand=true
```

This will ensure that when you build your module, only it's dependencies and itself are configured during the configuration phase.

Additionally you can also use the `-a` switch to execute only the module's tasks ignoring building its dependencies, if this is relevant.

```
gradle -a :core:test
```